# Is there a function to sort on the basis of a specific key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which I want to sort on the basis of its specific key before running foreach loop
I have tried ksort but It will not work on this sort of situation

```
[0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4829 (23) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(4) "4089"
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-31 06:28:57"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-31 06:28:57"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(48) "Sessions move 1 hour earlier from 30th September"
    ["post_title"]=> 'test'
}
[1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4830 (24) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(4) "4030"
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-31 06:28:57"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2018-10-31 06:28:57"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(48) "Sessions move 1 hour earlier from 30th September"
    ["post_title"]=> 'test'
}
```

This is the data I am fetching from my database and I want to show this in sorting order with respect to `post_date`. 
I need to sort this before running for each loop to show the courses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you use plain MySQL to get the array from the database.

Add `ORDER BY post_date` to your query.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to sort by post_date in your query.

However, if you really wants to do it using PHP you can use [array_multisort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

And use it like so :

For **PHP 5.6+** :

```
$dates = array_column($yourArray, 'post_date');

array_multisort($dates , SORT_NUMERIC, $yourArray);
```

In case of a **lower version of PHP** :

```
$dates=array();
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
   $dates[$key]  = $row['post_date'];
}

array_multisort($dates , SORT_NUMERIC, $yourArray);
```